# How do I create a link on an image in a CGI script?

Tags: perl, cgi

I can successfully show image in my CGI scripts via CGI.pm, using this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use CGI qw/:standard/;
print img {src => "../images/myimage.png", align=>"CENTER"};
```

However when  I want to do is to include URL in that image, wo that whenever 
people click on that image it will point to the desired url, this code   failed:

```
print img {src => "../images/myimage.png", align=>"CENTER", -href=>"www.google.com"};
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: How "it failed"? `http://www.google.com` instead of `www.google.com` would help?

Comment: @eumiro: Thanks but that didn't work either.

Comment: HTML image elements don't have an 'href' attribute. You need to create an anchor element around your image element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use CGI qw/:standard/;
print a( { href => 'http://www.google.com' }, img {src => "../images/myimage.png", align=>"CENTER" } );

# OUTPUT:
<a href="http://www.google.com"><img align="CENTER" src="../images/myimage.png" /></a>
```